# How to echo in php this specific javascript onclick button function

Tags: javascript, php

What i want is to echo this onclick function in php as when submitting a form. Anyone? Thanks

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="demo.showNotification('top','right')">Top Right</button>
```

Comment: `<?php echo "this onclick function"; ?>`

Comment: <?php echo "demo.showNotification('top','right')"; ?> i think my syntax with qoutes is wrong. not firing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the onsubmit attribuut in a form:

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="demo.showNotification('top','right')" method="post">
```

Comment: If the notification is a success notification but there would be an error while submmitting it would still show success, how to handle it if I am going to use it in the form tag?

Comment: Use onsubmit with return and return false if it fails, if false is returned it will not submit.